# How is the Dirac delta distribution defined in product of two functions?

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions

> A [Dirac distribution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dirac+distribution) or Dirac $\delta$-distribution $\delta(p)$ is the distribution that is given by evaluating a function at a point $p$.

That is, the Dirac $\delta(p)$ function is the distribution defined by $$\langle\delta(p),\phi \rangle=\phi(p)$$

This allows us to write $$\phi(p)=\int_0^1\delta(p)\phi(x)dx$$

Suppose we want to write

$$\int\phi(x)\phi(x)dx=\int\int_0^1\delta(
x-y)\phi(x)\phi(y)dxdy$$

How should we define $\delta(
x-y)$?

In this page [Free quantum fields](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/newideaofquantumfieldtheory-freequantumfields/) on example 14.4 they have
$\delta(
x-y) \in \Gamma'(E \boxtimes E)$ where  $\Gamma'(E \boxtimes E)$ is the dual of the space of section of the bundle  $\Gamma(E \boxtimes E)$  and
And $E$ is the real line bundle

Comment: What physical situation are you attempting to model?

Comment: Why is the integral from 0 to 1? moreover: that's not how the Delta works (it should be $\phi(p)=\int \delta(p-x)\phi(x)dx$ where integration is over the whole real line).

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618080/11127

Answer (score 4):

Your notation is inconsistent here: If you define $\delta(p)$ via $\langle \delta(p),f \rangle = f(p)$, then you have to write something like $f(p) = \int \delta(p)(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ for the integral notation.

A more common notation would be to write the point at which the $\delta$ evaluates as a subscript, i.e. $\langle \delta_p,f\rangle = f(p)$ and then the integral notation is $f(p) = \int \delta_p(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$. In that notation, integrating against $\delta(x-y)$ is simply another way to write $\delta_x(y)$ or $\delta_y(x)$, there is no need to define the action of a delta function on multiple functions: Your double integral in terms of the normal $\delta$ is
$$ \int \langle \delta_y, \phi(y)\cdot \phi \rangle\mathrm{d}y.$$

Comment: why would  $δ(p)$ depend  on $x$. According  to the defenition it is alinear map that eats a tests function $f$ and splits a  number $f(p)$?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira It's just how the notation works. The inner product $\langle f,g\rangle$ of two functions is $\int f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x$, so when you want to write $\langle \delta_p,f\rangle$ as an integral you write $\int \delta_p(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ even though $\delta_p$ technically is not a function and $\delta_p(x)$ *outside* of an integral doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @amiltonmoreira That doesn't change my answer. You can interpret what I wrote as a distribution on pairs of functions simply as $(f,g)\mapsto \int f(y)\langle \delta_y, g\rangle\mathrm{d}y$, which for $(f,g)$ from some space $V$ makes this a member of the dual space $V'$. There is no need to define the $\delta$ any differently.

Comment: in the integral  $\int \langle \delta_y, \phi(y)\cdot \phi \rangle\mathrm{d}y.$ means for each $y$ we have a distribution $\delta_y$?